# Question on Jenkins BitBucket using pipeline and pipeline script but also running when new data is pushed to bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have created an itiem using pipeline, and then in the pipeline selecting the pipeline script,
This allows me to run the build in stages. As below
[code]
pipeline {

```
agent any
tools  {
 terraform 'terraform-11'
}

stages {

     stage('Git Checkout terraform') {

        steps {
            git credentialsId: '********', url: 'https://******/********.git'
        }
    }

    stage('Terraform Init') {

        steps {
            sh 'terraform init'
        }
    }

    stage('Terraform A'){
        steps {
                  dir(dev){
                         sh 'terraform plan -var-file="terraform.tfvars"'
                         sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve'
                  }
             }
    }

    stage('Terraform B'){
        steps {
                  dir(env){
                         sh 'terraform plan -var-file="terraform.tfvars"'
                         sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve'
                  }
             }
    }

}
```

}
[/code]

This works very well, I take the code out and run a series of stages. There are more stages than this. What I would like to do is have the jenkins build run every time the terrform scripts are updated. I have look at examples but none of the examples are part of the PipeLine/PipeLine Script

There is Freestyle project, but it does not allow me to build all the stages I need.
There is PipeLine /Pipeline script from SCM which again does not allow me to build all the stages I need.

What I want to do is stick with my current pipeline, but set it so it can be run when scripts are pushed to Bitbucket. All I need is pointing at the right documentation. If this is possible. If its not possible, then I will go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the solution. I set up a Item that is a Folder, set up the Git Repo. Then I created a Jenkins file  called JenkinsFile with all the stages and steps. This is then uploaded to the repo being built. So the build will run the main item which the pulls in the JenkinsFile and runs it.